# How to serialize/deserialize nested hashtable to JSON?

Tags: android, json, hashtable

I have an android app. I use a following structure to store some data in `SharedPreferences`:

```
Hashtable<Integer, Hashtable<Size, Time>>
```

I do the serialization in following way:

```
private static String serialize(Hashtable<Integer, Hashtable<Size, Time>> results) {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    return gson.toJson(results);
}
```

and deserialization:

```
private Hashtable<Integer, Hashtable<Size, Time>> deserialize(String resultsJsonStr) {

    if (resultsJsonStr == null)
        return new Hashtable<>();
    else {
        Type typeOfHashMap = new TypeToken<Hashtable<Integer, Hashtable<Size, Time>>>() {}.getType();
        return new Gson().fromJson(resultsJsonStr, typeOfHashMap);
    }
}
```

However when I try to deserialize I receive the exception:

> com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 8 path $

My serialzied string look like:
{"3":{"4x4":"01:12:37 AM"}}

Comment: What is the `Time` class? Is it `java.sql.Time` or a custom class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `Time` objects are not serializable and you should present a serialize and deserialize mechanism for it. I have assumed that the `Time` class in your code is `java.sql.Time` which is child class of `java.util.Date`, so it has both:

`public long getTime() { ... }`

and

`public void setTime(long time) { ... }`

I have developed a sample code for it, you can change it as you want:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContext;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonParseException;
import com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive;
import com.google.gson.JsonSerializationContext;
import com.google.gson.JsonSerializer;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.sql.Time;
import java.util.Hashtable;

public class SerializeHelper {

    private static Gson gson;

    static {
        JsonSerializer<Time> serializer = new JsonSerializer<Time>() {
            @Override
            public JsonElement serialize(Time src, Type type, JsonSerializationContext context) {
                return src == null ? null : new JsonPrimitive(src.getTime());
            }
        };

        JsonDeserializer<Time> deserializer = new JsonDeserializer<Time>() {
            @Override
            public Time deserialize(JsonElement json, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
                return json == null ? null : new Time(json.getAsLong());
            }
        };

        gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapter(Time.class, serializer)
                .registerTypeAdapter(Time.class, deserializer).create();
    }

    public static String serialize(Hashtable<Integer, Hashtable<Size, Time>> results) {
        return gson.toJson(results);
    }

    public Hashtable<Integer, Hashtable<Size, Time>> deserialize(String resultsJsonStr) {
        if (resultsJsonStr == null)
            return new Hashtable<>();
        else {
            Type typeOfHashMap = new TypeToken<Hashtable<Integer, Hashtable<Size, Time>>>() {
            }.getType();
            return gson.fromJson(resultsJsonStr, typeOfHashMap);
        }
    }

}
```